# Use the binomial theorem to show that for any positive integer $n$, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i} = 2^n$.

Tags: probability, summation, solution-verification, binomial-theorem

Can somebody check to see if this is good enough just to show? It's very simple but the question doesn't say prove or anything like that.

So the binomial theorem states that $(x+y)^n=\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r}x^{n-r}y^r$

Let $x=1, y=1$.

Then $2^n=\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r}*1^{n-r}1^r$, which reduces to $2^n=\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r}$. Tada.

Good enough?

Comment: You got it. Looks good!

Comment: That is a proof.

Comment: Yes, it really is that simple.

Comment: The convention in maths questions is that "show" means "prove". Of course, it can be difficult sometimes to decide what you are entitled to assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid proof, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. If I might add an interpretation to the above result, it says that the total number of subsets from a set $A$ of $n$ items is $2^n$. You might run across that result in set theory or elementary real analysis.

Answer (score 1):

in the binomial theorem take a=b=1